# Fundamental period of a discrete-time signal

Tags: dsp

This question comes right out of the problems section of Oppenheim's [*Signals & Systems 2ed*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0138147574) textbook. **I don't understand the solution to the problem.**

(problem #1.35)
If a discrete-time complex sinusoid is expressed by \$x[n] = \exp(jmn2\pi/N)\$ (m is any integer), prove that the fundamental frequency is *N*<sub>0</sub> = N/gcd(N,m).

**Solution**: for a discrete-time signal to be periodic \$x[n]=  x[n+N_0]\$.
Substituting n+N0 into n and expanding that expression means that \$m(2\pi/N)N_0 = 2\pi{}k\$,
where k is *some* (not any) integer. Rearranging we get the expression *N*<sub>0</sub>=*N/(m/k)*.
somehow (*m/k*) = gcd(*N,m*).

I don't see it.

Comment: I added some math formatting to make it easier to read your question. But I also rearranged the first formula, putting *n* inside the exponential function, because I think this is the correct form for a complex exponential. Please revert if I changed the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write the book's solution out in more detail.

First, by definition, a discrete-time signal is periodic with period *N*<sub>0</sub> if for all *n*, \$x[n+N_0] = x[n]\$.

So we're interested in cases where

\$\exp(j2\pi{}mn/N) = \exp(j2\pi{}m(n+N_0)/N)\$.

We know that the complex exponential, considered as a continuous function, repeats whenever it's argument advances by \$2\pi\$. So our equality holds whenever the phase difference between the arguments increases by some multiple of \$2\pi\$, that is whenever there is a *k* such that

\$2\pi{}mn/N + 2\pi{}k = 2\pi{}m(n+N_0)/N\$.

We can eliminate terms here to get

\$ mn/N + k = mn/N + mN_0/N\$

and further

\$ k = mN_0/N \$

So the period of our discrete time function is

\$N_0 = Nk/m\$

But *N*<sub>0</sub> must be an integer, and we also want the smallest possible value of *N*<sub>0</sub> to get the *fundamental* frequency. That means we want the smallest *k* that makes *Nk/m* an integer.

Lets write this out in terms of the prime factors of *N* and *m*:

\$N_0 = \dfrac{k \Pi_p n_p}{\Pi_q m_q} \$

For this to be an integer we need *k* to be made up of all the factors of *m*, except the ones that are held in common with *N*.

\$ k = \dfrac{\Pi_q m_q}{\Pi_{\mathrm{common\ factors}} m_q}\$

But the numerator here is just *m*, and the denominator here is just the gcd of *N* and *m*, so we have

\$ m / k = \gcd(N, m)\$

which is what we were trying to show.

**TL;DR:** It's to make it work out so that *N*<sub>0</sub> is an integer.